# With AMP's image requirements, doesn't that mean every page (e.g. a desktop page) needs a 1200px-wide image?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, google-search-console

I'm using Wordpress + AMP for Wordpress plug-in in Transitional mode (also tried Reader Mode).

I'm receiving the "*Image size smaller than recommended size*" on a few pages in GSC. The solution says is to add a 1200px-wide image to each AMP page. Adding an image to 'each AMP page', however, means adding it to the regular Wordpress page/post. Frankly, a 1200px-wide image on these desktop pages looks daft and unnecessary. Here's an example: https://www.englishcurrent.com/etiquette-manners-upperintermediate-esl-lesson-plan/

Because of AMP's desire for an image on mobile, do desktop users have to endure a large 1200px image on each post? That doesn't seem like a good tradeoff. Hopefully I'm not understanding something here.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's what Google *recommends* for AMP pages. This is just a warning and not an error - and could be safely ignored. Basically, AMP is trying to make sure that the images appear decently on retina and high resolution displays. If you feel the images look good on your AMP pages, ignore the warning. You could also add 1200px images to your site and use image size and srcset filters to server users the correct size without affecting bandwidth or AMP pages.

Comment: @disinfor Thanks for the reply. It looks like srcset is the answer. I need a few days to read about it to see how to implement it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: You got it. Here are a couple resources to get you started: [alexwright.net](https://alexwright.net/blog/web-design/responsive-images-wordpress/) [andrewrminion.com](https://andrewrminion.com/2018/01/wordpress-responsive-images-srcset-sizes-attributes/)

Comment: I think maybe I misinterpreted AMP's guidelines. AMP requires a 1200px image per page, but that probably doesn't mean I need to have the image's width=1200px. When I upload my 1200px image to Wordpress, I can use one of the smaller sizes that WP automatically generates ("Thumbnail/Medium/Large/Custom Size") which WP already displays using srcset and size. I think this should still satisfy AMP because it can still access a 1200px to use for its carousel. That's my theory today.